# What is Anon Pages in Memory?

Tags: linux, memory

Recently one of my webservers consumed more memory, then I checked the `/proc/meminfo` and found that the AnonPages is the one consuming almost all the memory.

I tried to get understand this from some docs, but it's not clear, can someone help me what is actully, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the man pages of `proc(5)`:

```
AnonPages %lu (since Linux 2.6.18)
       Non-file backed pages mapped into user-space page tables.
```

The way a process maps memory in Linux is usually using the `mmap(2)` system call which "maps files or devices into memory".
The memory can be backed by an actual file in the disk, so you could handle a file as if it was a regular memory block.

However, you could also allocate empty memory section not backed by any file. Those memory pages are called "Anonymous". From the man page of `mmap`:

```
MAP_ANONYMOUS
       The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.
```

If you've ever programmed in C, you're probably familiar with `malloc(3)` and used it to allocate dynamic memory. In Linux, in most cases, under the hood `malloc` would actually call `mmap` to allocate Anonymous memory pages.

`AnonPages` shows the usage of the most common type of memory - dynamic memory areas that are used by process.

Note that allocating Anonymous pages using `mmap` or `malloc` will not necessarily be reflected immediately by the `AnonPages`; When you allocate dynamic memory, you just get a virtual address space that you can use, but the memory pages do not actually "instantiate" and mapped into the user-space memory of the process until it starts using them (write or read to/from a memory). Only then those memory pages are loaded to the RAM and accounted by `AnonPages`.

Simply put, `AnonPages` represents the first thing that probably pops to your mind by default when you think about "memory" and "RAM". Just "regular" memory pages dynamically allocated for processes by their request, and used by those processes. There's nothing really to "fix". It's expected and quite common for `AnonPages` to be the "top hitter".

You should just look for the processes that takes most amount of memory (for instance, using `top`) and act accordingly. Maybe there's a process that consumes large amount of memory (RSS), or many processes that fill up the memory.